How to delete asset folders in CraftCMS backend?
I created some asset folders which are displayed in the backend and which I would like to remove. I manually removed the directory on the server. It is still shown in the backend. The options in the dropdown are all greyed-in and there is no "Remove" option.


There should be a "Delete" option at the bottom of the element actions menu (i.e. the cogwheel at the bottom of the assets index), but it's only available for sub folders if only a single sub folder is selected.
Sub folders can also be deleted by clicking into them, and selecting "Delete folder" from the breadcrumb disclosure menu:

If neither of those options are available, your user account might be missing the required user permissions.

Many thanks. Now I found it ;-)
